# serial port listner in bash giving ERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)

Tags: bash, shell, serial-port

I am trying to create a listener for my embedded board. It returns multiple lines per command and I am not too sure of the eof formatting.
I use the following for the listener:

```
(stty raw speed 115200 cs8 -cstopb; cat > received.log) < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

The command in another shell is

```
printf "\r" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

It returns:
multiple runs of the command and each line formatted with

```
ERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)
^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^
```

I use printf to send all types of input

using :

```
printf "\n" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Gives :

```
ERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)
^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z^M^J^M^JERROR: Command is TOO LONG (max chars allowed = 354)^M^J^Z
```

Whats going on and how do I fix this? The serial port is 115200 8N1 with no hardware or software flow control.

Comment: Looks like the erro is coming from device side

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question about exactly where the `ERROR: Command is TOO LONG` message is coming from and how you're viewing it. I'm guessing that's what you're seeing in the `received.log` file?

Especially given that the error message you're getting back includes `^M^J` (which is another way of saying `\r\n`) sequences, my guess is that the device at the other end of the serial connection uses `\r\n` as the line-ending convention, like Windows or DOS. (Unix uses just `\n`, and there are also systems out there, such as old Macintosh OSes, that use just `\r`.)

Try changing your second command to:

```
printf "\r\n" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and see if that helps.